# work with docs files: Printing specific part of each paragraph in python

Tags: python, file, document, cpu-word, python-re

I have a list of articles in a doc file like this:

> [2]    World Bank Group, “Catalog Sources: World Development Indicators, data source: Food and Agriculture Organization, AQUASTAT data.” Oct. 15, 2014, [Online]. Available: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator.

> [3]    Ministry of Energy of Iran, “Implementation strategies for 40% reduction of agricultural water consumption in Zarrineh rood and Simineh rood basins,” Planning and Management Studies of Water Resources and Consumptions in Miyandoab Plain, Vol 1, 2016.

just need to print the name of each article that comes between " "

it's my code that makes access to paragraphs:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document("References.docx")

for para in doc.paragraphs:
    para = str(i.text.encode("utf-8"))
    print(i)
```

Comment: `print(para[para.index("“"):para.index("”")+1])`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will extract all strings within quotes for each paragraph as a list:

```
import re
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    para = str(i.text.encode("utf-8"))
    str_text = re.findall(r'“(.*?)”',para)
```

You can use str_text which is a list to get the required articles.